# Hazelcast memory leakage

Tags: hazelcast

I faced a problem using hazelcast IAtomic cluster logic. My Configuration is like that I have 4 nodes and first Node is master for hazelcast. Second node will be master if first node is going to down.
Scenario steps are:

1. I kill the **first node and third node the same time**.
2. Hazelcast decided to select a new master node because of master is died. The new master node is 2nd Node.
3. 2nd Node try to make migration and in here, system is going to **out of memory** because of Hazelcast. Hazelcast is trying to connect third node again-again (like infinite loop). In the end there will be no memory and system throw **OutOfMemoryException**

Hazelcast logs below

```
    Jul 10, 2018 2:52:36 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection
INFO: [198.168.10.11]:5702 [dev] [3.10.2] Connection[id=21282, /198.168.10.14:50491->/198.168.10.14:5702, endpoint=[198.168.10.14]:5702, alive=false, type=MEMBER] closed. Reason: Connection closed by the other side
Jul 10, 2018 2:52:36 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector
INFO: [198.168.10.11]:5702 [dev] [3.10.2] Connecting to /198.168.10.14:5702, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
Jul 10, 2018 2:52:36 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpAcceptor
INFO: [198.168.10.11]:5702 [dev] [3.10.2] Accepting socket connection from /198.168.10.14:56774
Jul 10, 2018 2:52:36 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnectionManager
INFO: [198.168.10.11]:5702 [dev] [3.10.2] Established socket connection between /198.168.10.14:5702 and /198.168.10.14:56774
Jul 10, 2018 2:52:36 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnectionManager
INFO: [198.168.10.11]:5702 [dev] [3.10.2] Established socket connection between /198.168.10.14:56774 and /198.168.10.14:5702
Jul 10, 2018 2:52:36 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnectionManager
WARNING: [198.168.10.11]:5702 [dev] [3.10.2] Wrong bind request from [198.168.10.11]:5701! This node is not the requested endpoint: [198.168.10.14]:5702
Jul 10, 2018 2:52:36 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection
INFO: [198.168.10.11]:5702 [dev] [3.10.2] Connection[id=21284, /198.168.10.14:5702->/198.168.10.14:55083, endpoint=null, alive=false, type=MEMBER] closed. Reason: Wrong bind request from [198.168.10.11]:5701! This node is not the requested endpoint: [198.168.10.14]:5702
Jul 10, 2018 2:52:36 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpAcceptor
INFO: [198.168.10.11]:5702 [dev] [3.10.2] Accepting socket connection from /198.168.10.14:51198
Jul 10, 2018 2:52:36 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnectionManager
INFO: [198.168.10.11]:5702 [dev] [3.10.2] Established socket connection between /198.168.10.14:5702 and /198.168.10.14:51198
Jul 10, 2018 2:52:36 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnectionManager
WARNING: [198.168.10.11]:5702 [dev] [3.10.2] Wrong bind request from [198.168.10.11]:5701! This node is not the requested endpoint: [198.168.10.14]:5702
Jul 10, 2018 2:52:36 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection
```

Node 1 and node 3 are on running the same server.
Node 2 and Node 4 are on running the same server

The configuration(to initialize hazelcast) is :

```
Config config = new Config();
    NetworkConfig network = config.getNetworkConfig();
    JoinConfig join = network.getJoin();
    join.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(true);
    join.getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(false);

    config.setNetworkConfig(network);
    config.setInstanceName("instance");
```

Comment: I'm using Hazelcast version 3.10.2

Comment: It's possible that remaining 2 members does not have enough heap space to carry all the data of 4 members, hence the oome. Did you consider the total data size you have on the cluster (lncluding backups), also the total heap size you have?

Comment: remaining nodes have 2GB memory when they are initialized. And also, Server has 4 gb extra memory. totally 6 gb memory is used. i think it is enough. If a kill only node 1 or node 3, there will be not problem. The problem is reprocuded only node1(master) and node3 are killed the same time.

Comment: is there anyone to suggest me a way to fix this issue ?

Comment: The use case and the description is not clear. It's best if you can attach logs of all members, and also take a heap dump by `-XX:HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` during OOME, so it can be investigated. You can attach the logs and maybe screenshot of the heap dump in a google post at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/hazelcast

Comment: Actually, Scenario is simple. totally, have 4 nodes. first 2 nodes are running on server1 and first node is master node. last 2 nodes are running server2. when i kill the first 2 nodes at the same time, hazelcast tries to connect died node again and again. I have heap dump. In my heap dump, 3nd node initialized 1GB memory and server2 has 8GB memory totally.  Also I saved max 50 long datas on hazelcast. I attached the Heap analyze result to question

Answer (score 1):

When i get the heap dump. I use MAT to analiyze and result is :
[image: MAT result]

[image: MAT Result]

Comment: The logs just indicate that a tcp connection is lost to a member, there's no information about afterwards. I also can not see the screenshots from those links, somehow they are broken. It'd be best if you can open a new thread on googlegroups with attached full logs and screenshots.